# Change Display Format Of List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, picker

I am using a Xamarin.Forms `Picker` and it's being populated by a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.  The issue is that it isn't displaying the way I would like.

XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="VersionPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

C#:

```
Dictionary<string, string> VersionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "asv1901", "American Standard Version" },
    { "bbe", "Bible In Basic English" },
};
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> VersionList = VersionDictionary.ToList();

VersionPicker.BindingContext = VersionList;
```

What it produces is like this...

```
[asv1901, American Standard Version]
```

I would like `Picker` to have something along these lines...

```
American Standard Version (asv1901)
```

Is there a way to do this?  XAML or C# would be fine (since it's purely a visual change, I was thinking XAML or a converter might make the most sense).

Comment: ItemDisplayBinding is used to bind the displayed text from your source.  Rather than use KeyValuePair, you could create your own class (or extend KVP) that included a Display property that was formatted the way you want.

Comment: Try following : var VersionList = VersionDictionary.AsEnumerable().Select(x => string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Value, x.Key).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng FYI... You need an extra `)` between `x.Key)` and `.ToList()`.

Comment: @jdweng That worked, perfectly.  I still don't have a handle on those lambda statements.  Hehehe...

Comment: @jdweng I also didn't realize that 'Picker' was just using any ole 'List<string>'.  I thought it has to be, somehow, bound to 'Dictionary<string>'.  Given that new knowledge, I could have 'foreach()' and 'Add()' to the children.

Comment: Also use VersionDictionary.AsEnumerable() to enumerate through keys of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A shout-out to jdweng (since he/she just did a comment and not an answer)...

```
Dictionary<string, string> VersionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "asv1901", "American Standard Version" },
    { "bbe", "Bible In Basic English" },
};
// take the dictionary<string, string>, turn it into an ienumerable<keyvaluepair<string, string>>, use linq to output the contents, format a new string based on those contents, turn it into list<string>
// "Bible In Basic English (bbe)"
var VersionList = VersionDictionary.AsEnumerable().Select(x => string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Value, x.Key)).ToList();

VersionPicker.BindingContext = VersionList;
```

To get that choice back to the appropriate format...

```
private void VersionPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selecteditem = VersionPicker.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // single quotes make it type Char while double quotes make it type String
    Char delimiter = '(';
    // create an array from the string separated by the delimiter
    String[] selecteditemparts = selecteditem.Split(delimiter);
    // take off the end space
    var selecteditemvalue = selecteditemparts[0].Substring(0, (selecteditemparts[0].Length - 1));
    // take off the end )
    var selecteditemkey = selecteditemparts[1].Substring(0, (selecteditemparts[1].Length - 1));
}
```

As a secondary option (and the one I ended up using)...

```
Dictionary<string, string> VersionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "asv1901", "American Standard Version" },
    { "bbe", "Bible In Basic English" },
};

var VersionList = new List<string>();

// keyvaluepair is a single instance and dictionary is a collection of keyvaluepairs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> version in VersionDictionary)
{
    var key = version.Key.ToUpper();
    var value = version.Value;
    // "Bible In Basic English (BBE)"
    VersionList.Add(string.Format("{0} ({1})", value, key));
}
```

It just makes more sense to my rather novice coding brain.  I'm sure jdweng's linq example is much more concise.